# How to access value of an axis in a label?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

```
...
        matrix {
            axes {
              axis {
                name 'FOO'
                values 'foo1' 'foo2'   // 
              }
...            stages {
                stage ('doIt') {
                    agent{
                      label '???'
                    }
                
...
```

I would like to build a `label` instruction that will accept `win` or `mac`, if also one of the values of FOO is found. How can I combine the value of the axis with the other strings to form a meaningful label?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the axis variable by its name - `FOO`. The only thing you need to keep in mind is to use it inside a double-quoted string, so the value can be interpolated correctly.

```java
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('Matrix example') {
            matrix {
                agent any
                axes {
                    axis {
                        name 'FOO'
                        values 'bar1', 'bar2', 'bar3'
                    }
                }
                stages {
                    stage('Test') {
                        agent {
                            label "${FOO}"
                        }
                        steps {
                            // ...
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```